# Set the time component of a DateTime variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

I am adding the add_2_calendar package to my flutter app and I need to set the time of when an event will happen.

for example:
I want an event to start at 10:00 am on Dec 29, 2023

I have a field where I pick the date (Dec 29, 2023) and field where I pick the time (10:00 am).

The field where I pick the date get the time when I picked the date (Dec 29, 2023 at 3:15PM).

How do I set a future time in the DateTime variable and Timestamp field of the db?

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

When I write this value to the Cloud Firestore db it is not capturing the time I have picked from the time picker.

The db field is a Timestamp field. The date saved to the db is Dec 29 but the time is 12:00:00 pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're facing an issue with setting a specific time for your events in Flutter using the add_2_calendar package and saving it to Cloud Firestore. Let's break down the process:

1. **DateTime Variable:**
   When you pick a date and time separately, you can create a `DateTime` variable and set both the date and time. For example:

   ```dart
   DateTime selectedDate = // Date picked from the date picker
   TimeOfDay selectedTime = // Time picked from the time picker

   DateTime eventDateTime = DateTime(
     selectedDate.year,
     selectedDate.month,
     selectedDate.day,
     selectedTime.hour,
     selectedTime.minute,
   );
   ```
2. **Firestore Timestamp:**
   When saving it to Cloud Firestore, ensure that you convert your `DateTime` variable to a `Timestamp` object. Firestore uses `Timestamp` to represent time.

   ```dart
   import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

   // Assuming 'events' is your Firestore collection
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events').add({
     'eventDateTime': Timestamp.fromDate(eventDateTime),
     // Other fields...
   });
   ```

   This should store the exact date and time you selected in the `eventDateTime` field.

Make sure to follow these steps when both reading and writing to the database to maintain consistency. If the issue persists, check your date and time conversion logic and make sure the values are correctly passed to the Firestore `Timestamp`.